# Hide part of url

Tags: java, html, jsp, liferay

Is there a way to hide part of the url of a certain page?

For example instead of **www.mypage.com/login&userid=0011/**

to show only **www.mypage.com/login**   ?

I am developing my webpage with Liferay and I am using jsp to show the content of the page and Java to complete the actions I want to be done.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The userid here is the 'request parameter'.

To hide request parameters use Post instead of Get.

The GET method is the **default** method to pass information from browser to web server and it produces a long string that appears in your browser's address bar.
Never use the GET method if you have password or other sensitive information to pass to the server.

e.g.

```
<form action="myForm.jsp" method="GET">
```

A generally more reliable method of passing information is the POST method.This method packages the information in exactly the same way as GET methods, but instead of sending it as a text string after a ? in the URL it sends it as a separate message.

e.g.

```
<form action="myForm.jsp" method="POST">
```

Comment: I am using post but the software Liferay for some reason it generates some long url. Thats why i was wondering if its possible to hide it. On the other hand I am passing the userId trough the url otherwise i cannot take it from the page because i am using for each loop to display all of the users in the portal and from there i want to edid a certain user. I accomplished that by making a url which will keep my userId.

Comment: So if you want to persist a userId why don't you include a field in your jsp page and make its input type as hidden.Then you can get its value, without showing up in the url. e.g. '<input type="hidden" name="Ric" value="French">'

Comment: because the for each loop is creating the fields and later on the action file is confused because all of the text fields are with the same name. and i dont want to use checkboxes because this allows multiple selection for deleting users and this is an issue too. Its like no ending circle :)

Comment: So have the hidden field (just 1) outside the loop, when the user in your application selects a value from within the loop created fields, populate that value into the hidden field (even by JavaScript would do) and then use it.

Comment: good idea. I just have to take an cell value from the table when the button is pressed. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String#substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method of `String` to take substring from the given string.

Try something like this:

```
String str = "www.mypage.com/login&userid=0011/";
String needed = str.substring(0,str.indexOf("&"));
```

Comment: The thing is that still the URL is the same. I want to hide it from the user not to see e when they open the page and look at the URL bar of the browser

Comment: @JohnRambo I dont think we can do that .

Answer (score 0):

In Apache you can create .htaccess-Files to accomplish that. I dont know, what it in jsp is, but i think you can easyly google it now.